# Does anyone know what terrain generation algorithm is used here?

Tags: algorithm, procedural-generation, terrain, procedural, fractal

Does anyone know what this terrain generation algorithm is called? I saw it in two places. [One was on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gyTyBU2pkKo), and the other, on Wikimedia.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to what Pikalek said, it's also known as the Midpoint Displacement algorithm (because you perturb the midpoints of each edge) or [Diamond-Square algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm) when working with a square instead of a triangle.

Answer (score 2):

I've seen it referred to as 'fractal subdivision.' In this case, you assign a random height perturbation to the corners of the triangle, subdivided it at the midpoints of the edges & repeat the process over again for each triangle until some threshold is met.